# Extracting the Author and Comments from Word to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have the following code which extracts strings of text from a Word document and exports it into an Excel spreadsheet. Column A reads the comments and Column B reads the original text that it refers to. I'd like to also extract the Author who made the comment into the spreadsheet but not sure how to. Thanks.

```
    Option Explicit




   Public Sub FindWordComments()
'Requires reference to Microsoft Word v14.0 Object Library

Dim objExcelApp As Object
Dim wb As Object
Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\cetraig\Documents\Projects\_HRBT\Book1.xlsx")

Dim myWord              As Word.Application
Dim myDoc               As Word.Document
Dim thisComment         As Word.Comment

Dim fDialog             As Office.FileDialog
Dim varFile             As Variant

Dim destSheet           As Worksheet
Dim rowToUse            As Integer
Dim colToUse            As Long

Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
Set destSheet = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
colToUse = 1

With fDialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Import Files"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Word Documents", "*.docx"
    .Filters.Add "Word Macro Documents", "*.docm"
    .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"
End With

If fDialog.Show Then

    For Each varFile In fDialog.SelectedItems

        rowToUse = 2

        Set myWord = New Word.Application
        Set myDoc = myWord.Documents.Open(varFile)

        For Each thisComment In myDoc.Comments

            With thisComment
                destSheet.Cells(rowToUse, colToUse).Value = .Range.Text
                destSheet.Cells(rowToUse, colToUse + 1).Value = .Scope.Text
                destSheet.Columns(2).AutoFit
            End With

            rowToUse = rowToUse + 1

        Next thisComment

        destSheet.Cells(1, colToUse).Value = Left(myDoc.Name, 4)
        'Put name of interview object in cell A1

        destSheet.Cells(1, colToUse + 1).Value = ActiveDocument.Words.Count
        'Put the number of words in cell B1

        Set myDoc = Nothing
        myWord.Quit

        colToUse = colToUse + 2

    Next varFile

    End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a line with:

```
destSheet.Cells(rowToUse, colToUse + 2).Value = .Author
```

Should do the trick

(assuming you want it in the next column over)

Comment: Is it supposed to not open up automatically? When I run it Word asks me to Import File so I open my Word doc that I already have open.. then the code goes with no errors but my Excel file doesn't open up automatically and it doesn't update either when I go into it after running the code

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question and clarify what the problem is, I understood you wanted to know how to extract the author of a comment.

Comment: @IgnacioCetrangolo The question you asked (implied, really) has been addressed with this answer. If you have other questions about your code, post a NEW QUESTION. And mark this one as answered, or explain how this answer does not answer *the question you asked*.